# Unable to append child on vanilla JS due to document.getElementById() and document.querySelector() not returning nodes, unlike jQuery's $()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't do:

```
document.querySelector("#myDiv").appendChild("<img src='./img/mine.png' class='mine hidden'></img>");
```

or:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild("<img src='./img/mine.png' class='mine hidden'></img>");
```

Both methods put text inside the div they're called on. The only thing that works is:

```
$("#myDiv").append("<img src='./img/mine.png' class='mine hidden'></img>");
```

I believe it is because vanilla JS alternatives to jQuery's $() don't return nodes.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv"))
console.log(document.querySelector("#myDiv"))
console.log($("#myDiv"))
document.getElementById("myDiv").append("<p>Hi</p>")
document.querySelector("#myDiv").append("<p>Hi</p>")
$("#myDiv").append("<p>Hi</p>")
```

```css
div {
height: 80px;
background-color: green;
width: 100%;
}

p {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Well because they return null so that is expected. What are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: Perhaps this is a timing issue?  Does the node exist when vanilla JS is run? (on dom ready, on page loaded?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS has a function for setting the inner value of a HTML node.

Maybe try this instead of the append function:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/mine.png' class='mine hidden'></img>"
```

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild()` expects a Node, not a string as jQuery's `append()` does. As such you can make this work by creating an `img` element and then providing that as an argument to `appendChild()`, like this:

```js
var img = new Image(); // alternative: document.createElement('img');
img.src = './img/mine.png';
img.className = 'mine hidden';
document.querySelector("#myDiv").appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```